# SAS Proc SQL Loop (?) to pull from a table that exists in multiple libraries

Tags: sql, loops, sas, proc

I'm trying to write SQL that pulls from 3 'versions' of a single dataset (DSET), that's present in multiple libraries (LIB16, LIB17, LIB18), where the only variable is the YY in the library name.

My current code is something like...

```
    PROC SQL;
       CREATE TABLE DSET16_18 AS 
       SELECT * FROM LIB18.DSET
    UNION
       SELECT * FROM LIB17.DSET
    UNION
       SELECT * FROM LIB16.DSET
    ;QUIT;
```

Instead of the above, is this possible via some kind of loop?

Few side notes:
No data steps please (don't ask, it's complicated); 
I realize my current code works fine, that's not the point;
No this is not for school, I'm just in over my head at work :D

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: You said no datasteps. Are other PROCs are OK? Can you use macros?

Comment: Could be accomplished using proc lua

Answer (score 0):

If you can use macro, you can do loop in it.

```
%let start=16;
%let end=18;

%macro genSQL();

%macro d;
%mend d;

PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE DSET&start._&end. AS 

    SELECT * FROM LIB&start..DSET

        %do i=&start.+1 %to &end.;
        %if %sysfunc(exist(LIB&i..DSET)) %then %do;
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM LIB&i..DSET
            %end;
        %end;
    ;
QUIT;

%mend genSQL;

%genSQL;
```

If you set parameters start and end to 1 and 20, then macro generate the next code:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE DSET1_20 AS    
SELECT * FROM LIB1.DSET     UNION    
SELECT * FROM LIB2.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB3.DSET     UNION    
SELECT * FROM LIB4.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB5.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB6.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB7.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB8.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB9.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB10.DSET     UNION  
SELECT * FROM LIB11.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB12.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB13.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB14.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB15.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB16.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB17.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB18.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB19.DSET     UNION   
SELECT * FROM LIB20.DSET
;
QUIT;
```

Comment: You might want to also track the library source of the records … `select "LIB1" as lib, * from LIB1.DSET  UNION …`

Comment: Sorry I deleted that comment - the error was my fault, your code works great!

Answer (score 0):

Solution with *macro* and *dictionary.tables*:

```
%let mQuery=;
%let min=2;
%let max=4;

proc sql noprint;
   select "SELECT * FROM " || strip(libname) || '.' || strip(memname) 
   into: mQuery separated by " UNION " 
   from dictionary.tables 
   where libname LIKE "LIB%" and 
         memname = "DSET" and 
         input(strip(tranwrd(libname,"LIB","")),numx.) between &min and &max;
quit;

%macro create_table(tQuery,tMin,tMax); %macro d;%mend d;

%if "&tQuery" ne "" %then %do;

proc sql noprint;
   create table test&&tMin._&tMax. as &tQuery;
quit;

%end;

%mend create_table;


%create_table(&mQuery,&min,&max);
```

`min` is number of first lib, and `max` is the number of last lib.

`%if "&tQuery" ne "" %then %do;` this condition checks, `&mQuery` is empty or not. If it is empty, then query wouldn't be complete and would no error.

`&mQuery` is macro variable that with `min=2` and `max=4` looks like :

```
SELECT * FROM LIB2.DSET UNION SELECT * FROM LIB3.DSET UNION SELECT * FROM LIB4.DSET
```

In addition, if you want to exclude some libs in interval *min-max*, then just add one more condition in `proc sql` :

```
input(strip(tranwrd(libname,"LIB","")),numx.) not in(3,5);
```

This condition will exclude `LIB3.DSET` and `LIB5.DSET` .